# Chat that works without AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I've come across a live chat on a website and i was wondering how it would work?

The reason being is i thought it would be the normal AJAX based chat where it updates the messages by sending an AJAX request x amount of seconds or by using PHP sleep() to keep the connection open until new messages were sent.

However upon inspecting it using firebug, i couldn't see any AJAX requests being sent, when i was sending a message and when new messages were being retrieved. How does this work?

Comment: Probably WebSockets.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely using the Websockets protocol: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API. However, it's also possible it's using Flash.

Comment: Is there anything in particular you need to have in order to use web sockets over ajax?